# looping around vectors in R

Tags: r, loops, generics, vector

I am trying to optimize the code below

```
lv1=length(new.variable1.v)
lv2=length(new.variable2.v)
lv3=length(new.variable3.v)
lv4=length(new.variable4.v)
lv5=length(new.variable5.v)
```

Example of values of one vector

```
new.variable1.v
 [1] 193 194 196 197 198 199 201 202 203 204 205 206 208 209 210 211
```

I have tried this but it doesn't work

```
for (i in 1:5){
paste0("lv",i,"")=length(paste0(paste("new.variable", i, sep =""),".","v"))
  }
```

Comment: If you find yourself defining R objects with names like `foo1`, `foo2`, etc. and then to make matters worse, you want to do similar things to all of them, that's a sure sign that you made a mistake in not putting all those objects in a single list structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get the 'new.variable' in a `list`, get the `length` of each of the 'list' element with  `lengths`.  set the names of the vector using `paste`, convert to a `list` and create new objects using `list2env`

```
l1 <- lengths(mget(ls(pattern = "new.variable\\d+\\.v")))
l2 <- setNames(l1, paste0("lv", seq_along(l1)))
list2env(as.list(l2), envir = .GlobalEnv)
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
new.variable1.v <- sample(190:220, 10, replace=FALSE)
new.variable2.v <- sample(150:180, 15, replace=FALSE)
new.variable3.v <- sample(190:220, 20, replace=FALSE)
new.variable4.v <- sample(150:180, 8, replace=FALSE)
new.variable5.v <- sample(190:220, 21, replace=FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked.just a short follow up. If I want to loop around vectors v1,v2,v3

Comment: I need to use this? ls(pattern = "new.variable\\d+\\.v"). This is mainly what I am trying to understand.

Comment: @user4797853  If you have around 100 objects in your global environment, it is difficult to type each object name separately, so by using `ls()` this extract the object names with the pattern specified and `mget` gives the values of the objects in a `list`

Comment: Thank you, this is a great explanation

Answer (score 1):

@joran is right in the comment above. Save your variables into a list, like this one:

```
myList <- list(A = 1:3, B = 1:4, C = 1:5)
```

Then you can just use one of the `apply` functions -- here, `sapply` because you may want the return to be a vector. Use `lapply` if you'd rather have a list.

```
sapply(myList, length)
```

outputs:

```
A B C 
3 4 5
```

Answer (score 0):

This works if you don't mind your vector sizes being in a list

```
vectors <- list(v1=1:5,v2=2:6)

vector_sizes <- list(v1Size=NA, v2Size=NA)

for(i in 1:length(vectors)) {
  print(vectors[i])
  vector_sizes[i] <- length(unlist(vectors[i]))
}

vector_sizes
```

But its not optimized, the below is much faster

```
sapply(vectors, length)
```